# Tweepy Psycopg2 creating points, coordinate system SRID confusing

Tags: point, geometry, psycopg2

I am using Tweepy and Psycopg2 to extract tweets and input them in a PostgreSQL table. When I try to insert the point of the tweet I succeed in creating a point in the geom column I create. I however do not succeed in getting a basemap aligned behind it, while I thought I had the tweets in SRID=4326 which is WGS84.

Is there something wrong with my script? I suppose the basemap is not wrong but I can't be sure.

```
cur.execute("SELECT AddGeometryColumn('public', 'test', 'geom', 4326, 'POINT', 2)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Test(geom) VALUES(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s,%s),4326))",(tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][0],tweet.coordinates['coordinates'][1]))
        con.commit()
```

Or are Tweepy points just not in WGS84? I thought they were.

*** update 
This is my search statement

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="*",since="2016-02-10", until="2016-02-29", count=100000, geocode="5.29126,52.132633,150km").items(10000000):
```

Expecting the tweets to be in the Netherlands and parts of Belgium and Germany.

I did make some steps getting tweets in Belgium on  the right location. But it's still weird. I load in a basemap in EPSG::3857 and then need to put the tweets on EPSG::4326 and they align. When I put them in the same CRS they do not align.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the tweet.coordinates parameter that you're having trouble with? Like you I'm pretty sure that the coordinates from twitter are simply WGS84 longitude/latitude. Also, are you using streaming or searching to get the tweets with coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a plugin for QGIS called [twitter2qgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/geotweet/) which fetches data from twitter firehorse.
The coordinates in tweets are in EPSG:4326 if they are provided.. 
and the geocode must be in [lat,lon,radius](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.search). Yours are in lon,tat,radius:

geocode="5.29126,52.132633,150km" --> geocode="52.132633,5.29126,150km"